# Dump gltf model to png

Tags: c++, gltf

Is it possible to create an image representation of a gltf model using the [tinygltf](https://github.com/syoyo/tinygltf) library?

I see [this example](https://github.com/syoyo/tinygltf/blob/release/examples/gltfutil/main.cc) contains the notion of a "dumper" to save textures as png/jpeg etc. After trying it out with a simple mesh, I get the warning

> "model file has 0 textures."

which makes me wonder whether this dumper can store my "view" of the mesh as an image or the dumper is just a utility to "flush" textures contained in the model.

Comment: The texure dumper dumps textures. I think what you are looking for is called "snapshot".

Comment: @Wyrzutek but is there such a functionality ? I can't find any mention of "snapshot" in the repo

Comment: "an image representation of a gltf model" sounds very much like taking a screenshot of a 3D rendered object. Which would require a full renderer to create such a visual representation. I therefore doubt that it would be built into a parsing library, though you might be able to extract the required code from one of the viewer examples in it

Comment: The tinygltf library is just for parsing & loading the file, it doesn't actually render the glTF. Creating a rendered snapshot of the 3D asset stored in a glTF file is a complex topic, requiring a rendering engine of some sort.  For example see: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Viewer